# Can I pass an array per move reference to std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, reference

I want to do something like this:

```
void
Bah::f (std::vector <int> && array)
{
   std::thread (&Bah::foo, this, std::move (array)) .detach ();
}

void
Bah::foo (const std::vector <int> & array)
{
  do something with array
}
```

The question is: can I pass an array (variable) per move reference to std::thread and then access as const reference in the thread function? Is the array moved before the thread function is called?

What I want to achieve is, I want the array to be empty after the call of »f«. And when »foo« is called I dont want a copy of the array.

Comment: Yes, I think, so, since the thread's storing of arguments works as if `std::decay` is applied to each argument type. At that point the vector contents should be moved. But do test it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move in the vector this way. See a mini-example below, illustrating the move (actually 4 moves are going to happen to pass the argument to the thread).

One extra remark: you shouldn't rely on the fact that move makes the vector empty. If you need the vector to be empty after the call into `f`, you should explicitly call `clear` on it. In practice the vector will likely be empty, but that is unspecified, the standard allows it to be in any "valid" state.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy A" << endl; }
    A(A&&) { cout << "move A" << endl; }
};

class B
{
public:
    void bar() 
    { 
        A a;
        thread(&B::foo, this, move(a)).detach(); 
    }
    void foo(const A&) { return; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.bar();
}

// Output:
// move A
// move A
// move A
// move A
```